# Outlier identification -- 3s control limits or 1.5IQR

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, outliers, quantiles

I am would like to implement outlier flag (extreme user) identification on our data system. We have a daily database that shows each user usage (in minutes). A simple statistical control would be either 3s control limits or 1.5 IQR . The thing is there is big different between these two statistical limit control . So I was wandering which one is recommended by statistician

ex (number in minutes) :

sd control limit:

```
mean = 99
sd = 165

2s control limits = 429
3s control limits = 594
```

so x > 429 (or x> 594 if we choice 3s control limit) will flag as an outlier or extreme users

```
1.5*IQR method 
quantile 25% = 10
quantile 75% = 90
IQR = 80

quantile 75% + 1.5*IQR = 210 == Upper limit
```

here x > 210 will flag as an outlier or extreme users

Comment: This is where you would use your knowledge of the subject matter to say what would constitute an extreme value. Is 211 extreme and worth examining in detail? 430? 595? I’m also curious what you’ll do once you identify an outlier. It’s generally recommended not to remove observations from the analysis just because they’re extreme.

Comment: @Dave it is very good question. These are game application usage and it is really depends on the game. For example for game 200 mins is extreme usage but for game B 200 mins is a light usage and 400 is somehow extreme. I want to flag outlier atm to see what % of total usage coming from extreme users. I donot want to  remove observations from the analysis just because they’re extreme as you stated

Comment: It sounds like you have an idea of what "extreme" means for each game. Use that knowledge.

Comment: If you ever need the exact same thing, you know where I am. thx!

Comment: I don't follow, but I'm glad I could help.